# PHP / MySQL: Image successfully save to database but failed to display at web page

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a very weird problem in my system. I already create a system to upload the image to the database and display it. The problem is, the image is successfully uploaded but, it will return the message "Failed to upload!". Then, the picture that had been uploaded does not display. Below is my code:

```
    <body>

        <div class="wrapperDiv">
            <form action="" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Upload image : 
                <input type="file" name="uploadFile" value="" />
                <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" />
            </form>


            <?php
            $last_insert_id = null;
            include('db2.php');
            if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']) && !empty($_POST['submitBtn'])) {
                if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'])) {
                    //Allowed file type
                    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

                    //File extension
                    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                    //Check extension
                    if(in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions)) {
                        //Convert image to base64
                        $encoded_image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']));
                        $encoded_image = $encoded_image;
                        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images SET encoded_image = '".$encoded_image."'";
                        $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
                        $sql -> execute();
                        //$results = $sql -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                        echo "File name : " . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
                        echo "<br>";
                        if($sql->rowCount() > 1 ) {
                            echo "Status : Uploaded";
                            $last_insert_id = $conn-> lastInsertId(); 
                        } else {
                            echo "Status : Failed to upload!";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "File not allowed";
                    }
                }

                if($last_insert_id) {
                    $query = "SELECT encoded_image FROM tbl_images WHERE id= ". $last_insert_id;
                    $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $sql -> execute();
                    if($sql->rowCount($sql) == 1 ) {
                        //$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
                        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<br><br>";
                        echo '<img src="'.$row->encoded_image.'" width="250">';

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try this, if(in_array(strtolower($ext), $allowed_extensions)) {

Comment: I think you need to add <img src="data:image/png;base64, ........."  />
Add data:image/png in between src tag before the image encoded string.

Comment: @VikashDhiman echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$row->encoded_image.'" width="250">';

like this? still failed

Comment: @manu failed also

Answer (score 0):

you doing some thing wrong first you encoded the image when store in database so you must decode it again, and the src in  tag get a url not image content just echo the content like this:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo base64_decode($row->encoded_image);
```

or

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$row->encoded_image.'" width="250">
```

but at all, store images in database is not a good option, your database become too heavy and can't respond fast and get too memory you can just store the image name in database and move the file form special place in your server the you can show like this.

```
echo '<img src="specialRoot/'.$row->image_name.'" width="250">';
```

Comment: Can you edit my code at the question above? I still dont understand

Answer (score -1):

Store images in folder..
I have created uploads folder in root, you can create folder at anywhere and write your path while fetching the image..

```
<body>

    <div class="wrapperDiv">
        <form action="" method="post" id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Upload image : 
            <input type="file" name="uploadFile" value="" />
            <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Upload" />
        </form>


        <?php
        $last_insert_id = null;
        include('db2.php');
        if(isset($_POST['submitBtn']) && !empty($_POST['submitBtn'])) {
            if(isset($_FILES['uploadFile']['name']) && !empty($_FILES['uploadFile']['name'])) {
                //Allowed file type
                $allowed_extensions = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");
                $name = $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
                $target_dir = "uploads/";   //give path of your folder where images are stored.
                $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
                $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                //Check extension
                if( in_array($imageFileType,$allowed_extensions) ){
                    //Convert image to base64

                    $image_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']) );
                    $encoded_image = 'data:image/'.$imageFileType.';base64,'.$image_base64;

                    //$encoded_image = base64_encode($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name']);
                    //$encoded_image = $encoded_image;
                    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images SET encoded_image = '".$encoded_image."'";
                    $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
                    $result = $sql -> execute();
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'],$target_dir.$name);
                    echo "File name : " . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
                    echo "<br>";

                    if($result == 1) {
                        echo "Status : Uploaded";
                        $last_insert_id = $conn->insert_id;
                    } else {
                        echo "Status : Failed to upload!";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "File not allowed";
                }
            }

            if($last_insert_id) {

               $query = "SELECT encoded_image FROM tbl_images WHERE id= ". $last_insert_id;
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo '<img src="'.$row['encoded_image'].'" width="250">';
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
```